How to use isReadyOrError?
How to use isReadyOrError? I see no example in the doc and the error never shows up in my minimal example below:
try {
  const wsProvider = new WsProvider("wss://this.will.not.work");
  api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider, throwOnConnect: true });
  await api.isReadyOrError;
} catch (err) {
  console.log("this never shows up", err);
}

Is there a timeout? How to make sure that the error shows up if the connection can not be established in a given amount of time?

The connection to the node endpoint is handled by WsProvider, not ApiPromise. Once you call new WsProvider(), it immediately starts attempting to connect and will keep retrying every 2.5 seconds. If you want to control this process manually, you can do it as follows:
try {
  // Sleep in asynchronous function
  const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

  // The second argument is autoConnectMs. (2500 by default)
  // Disable auto-connection by passing 0 or false.
  const provider = new WsProvider('ws://localhost:9944', false);

  let retry = 0;
  while (retry < 5) {
    await provider.connect();
    
    if (provider.isConnected) {
      console.info('connected');
      break;
    }

    console.warn('disconnected');
    retry += 1;
    await sleep(2500);
  }

  const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider });
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}

